# Priority of SQL Server log files

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL SERVER 2005 standard edition.

I have a "small" but fast hard drive and "big" and slow hard drive.  Sometimes there is not enough space on the "small" drive for my SQL server database log file.  So I restricted the size of the log file on the fast drive and created another one on slow drive.  I hoped that SQL server would use first log file on the fast drive till it was full and then switched to second one.  But I see that SQL server started with second log file.

Question:  is it possible to specify which log file must be used first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. For example: set file grow in 100 MB for the "fast" log and 1 MB for the "slow" log. Then they will be filling in proportion of file frow setting (100/1 in this case). When "fast" log file will be full, only "slow" log will be working. This is not an ideal solution, but at least something.

Comment: Good thinking. Better to detach, drop LDFs, single file attach though

Answer (score 0):

No Multiple log files don’t really help

Edit:

Better to detach, drop LDFs, single file attach though...

Comment: Well...  It does not help perfomance, but if you don't have enough space you just have no choice

Comment: Pethaps but you still cannot specify which file first. Buy a bigger faster array for the logs instead of trying to be clever. Is performance important or not?

Comment: Trying to be clever never hurts.  Thanks anyway

Comment: There is a way.  For example:  set file grow in 100 MB for the "fast" log and 1 MB for the "slow" log.  Then they will be filling in proportion of file frow setting (100/1 in this case).  When "fast" log file will be full, only "slow" log will be working.  This is not an ideal solution, but at least something.